# bash scripting - case statement not evaluating string (values) correctly

Tags: bash, shell, unix, case

I need help figuring out why my `case` statement is not properly evaluating my first 2 values (visitor_id, updated) in my list.
Here's the code:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/bash
file="mydatasample.out";
linecount=$(wc -l <"$file" | awk '{ print $1 }')
counter=1
while IFS='' read -r column; do
  case column in
    visitor_id)
       echo "isnull($column|| '[|]' ||";;
       updated)
       echo "isnull($column::text || '[|]' ||";;
             *)
       echo "isnull($column::text,'[null!]') || '[|]' ||";;
  esac
  if [ "$counter" -eq "$linecount" ]; then
      echo "isnull($column::text,'[null!]')) as md5sum"
  fi
  ((counter++))
done <"$file"
```

`=mydatasample.out=`

```
visitor_id
updated
visitor_1_key
visitor_1_value
visitor_2_key
visitor_2_value
```

**Getting:**

```
isnull(visitor_id::text,'[null!]') || '[|]' ||
isnull(updated::text,'[null!]') || '[|]' ||
isnull(visitor_1_key::text,'[null!]') || '[|]' ||
isnull(visitor_1_value::text,'[null!]') || '[|]' ||
isnull(visitor_2_key::text,'[null!]') || '[|]' ||
isnull(visitor_2_value::text,'[null!]')) as md5sum
```

**Expecting:**

```
isnull(visitor_id|| '[|]' ||
isnull(updated::::text || '[|]' ||
isnull(visitor_1_key::text,'[null!]') || '[|]' ||
isnull(visitor_1_value::text,'[null!]') || '[|]' ||
isnull(visitor_2_key::text,'[null!]') || '[|]' ||
isnull(visitor_2_value::text,'[null!]')) as md5sum
```

So, its the first (2) values that I want to evaluate, but so far cannot. Thanks for your help.

Comment: did you mean `case "$column" in ...` ?

Comment: could be..is it as simple as that? i will try. thanks

Comment: [shellcheck](http://shellcheck.net) autodetects this and other common problems. You can consider installing it in your editor.

Comment: Another suggestion: rather than all the `linecount` and `counter` stuff, just put the `echo "... as md5sum"` command *after* the loop, so it runs with the last value of `$column`.

Comment: @GordonDavisson - interesting, i still don't understand how it knows to get the last value. would you mind showing me that? thank you.

Comment: @noober: Actually, I take it back; that wouldn't work. `read` sets `column` to each line as it's read, but after the last line there's a final `read` that reads the end-of-file and sets `column` to null. But if you add `lastcolumn=$column` inside the loop, then after the loop that'll have the last actual column left in the `column` variable, and you can use that to print the "... as md5sum".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`case`, unlike `for`, doesn't interpret `column` as `$column` (because `for` needs to know the name of the variable to assign to, while `case` needs to know the value to compare it).

You probably wanted

```
case "$column" in
```

Comment: yay! thank you very much. quick fix for sure. appreciate the help!